# why asyncio.Queue could not work as expected?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq, python-asyncio

I am writing simple producer/consumer program.

```
import zmq

@asyncio.coroutine
def receive_data(future,s):
        print("begin to recv sth from.....socket"
        my_data = s.recv()
        future.set_result(my_data)

@asyncio.coroutine
def producer(loop,q,s):
        while True:
                future = asyncio.Future()
                yield from receive_data(future,s)
                data = str(future.result())
                yield from q.put(data)
@asyncio.coroutine
def consumer(loop,q):
       while True:
          a = yield from q.get()
          print("i am get..."+str(a)+"..."+str(type(a)))  
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

c = zmq.Context()
s = c.socket(zmq.REP)
s.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5515')

q = asyncio.Queue()
tasks=[asyncio.Task(producer(loop,q,s)),asyncio.Task(comsumer(loop,q))]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
loop.close()
s.close()
```

It appears the consumer has no chance to execute.

The sockets receive data every 500ms, so when `yield from` in receive_data function suspends the producer coroutine, the consumer coroutine will print info.

What could explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s.recv()` is blocking call, so `receive_data` hungs until new ZMQ message arrives.

That blocks event loop and consumer has no chance to execute itself.

You can pass `zmq.NOBLOCK` flag to `.recv` and call `asyncio.sleep(0)` if no data available to give eventloop a chance to iterate over other ready tasks.

Or just use [aiozmq](http://aiozmq.readthedocs.org) library :)

Comment: Or you can use a ROUTER/DEALER instead as it is kind of an asynchronous request-reply pattern. See [request-reply recap documentation](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Recap-of-Request-Reply-Sockets)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous calls, the results will be synchronous.
If you want to keep using asyncio, you should define an asynchronous context `c = zmq.asyncio.context()` and use ROUTER socket `s = c.socket(zmq.ROUTER)`. Then, following asyncio syntax, you should yield from `recv_multipart()` so your `my_data = s.recv()` becomes `my_data = yield from s.recv_multipart()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guideline of what needs to happen:

- you should use `Context` and `ZMQEventLoop` from `zmq.asyncio`
- you should make `asyncio` use the zmq loop by calling `set_event_loop()`
- for testing purposes only, I have switched to a ROUTER_RAW socket

Working example:

```
import asyncio
import zmq
from zmq.asyncio import Context, ZMQEventLoop

async def receive_data(s):
        data = await s.recv()
        print('receive_data', data)
        return data

async def producer(q, s):
        while True:
                data = await receive_data(s)
                await q.put(data)

async def consumer(q):
       while True:
          a = await q.get()
          print('i got... {} ... {}'.format(a, type(a)))  

loop = ZMQEventLoop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

c = Context()
s = c.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
s.setsockopt(zmq.ROUTER_RAW, 1)
s.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5515')

q = asyncio.Queue()
tasks=[producer(q, s), consumer(q)]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
loop.close()
s.close()
```

You can test it out with ROUTER_RAW using telnet:

```
$ telnet localhost 5515
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
test
abcd1234
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
$
```

The response from the app for this would be:

```
receive_data b'\x00\xa3\x8e\x1f)'
receive_data b''
i got... b'\x00\xa3\x8e\x1f)' ... <class 'bytes'>
i got... b'' ... <class 'bytes'>
receive_data b'\x00\xa3\x8e\x1f)'
receive_data b'test\r\n'
i got... b'\x00\xa3\x8e\x1f)' ... <class 'bytes'>
i got... b'test\r\n' ... <class 'bytes'>
receive_data b'\x00\xa3\x8e\x1f)'
receive_data b'abcd1234\r\n'
i got... b'\x00\xa3\x8e\x1f)' ... <class 'bytes'>
i got... b'abcd1234\r\n' ... <class 'bytes'>
receive_data b'\x00\xa3\x8e\x1f)'
receive_data b''
i got... b'\x00\xa3\x8e\x1f)' ... <class 'bytes'>
i got... b'' ... <class 'bytes'>
```